# Adding Custom taxonomies to Press This panel

Tags: custom-taxonomy

How do I add a custom taxonomy & be able to search it right in the Press This editor as if it were a standard category or tag?

Here's the code in the Press-This.php file in wp-admin. I'm presuming I can customize this from functions.php?

```
<?php

/**
 * Press This Display and Handler.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Press_This
 */

define('IFRAME_REQUEST' , true);

/** WordPress Administration Bootstrap */
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/admin.php' );

if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) || ! current_user_can( get_post_type_object( 'post' )->cap->create_posts ) )
    wp_die( __( 'Cheatin&#8217; uh?' ), 403 );

if ( empty( $GLOBALS['wp_press_this'] ) ) {
    include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-press-this.php' );
}

$GLOBALS['wp_press_this']->html();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're talking about Custom Post Type, not Custom Taxonomy. Right?

If yes, add this code on your `functions.php` file:

```
function press_this_ptype($link) {
    $post_type = 'example';

    $link = str_replace('post-new.php', "post-new.php?post_type=$post_type", $link);
    $link = str_replace('?u=', '&u=', $link);

    return $link;
}
add_filter('shortcut_link', 'press_this_ptype', 11);
```

Once you add the correct Post Type, Wordpress will detect all taxonomies attached to it automatically (if they're specified on the custom taxonomy code, obviously).

You can have multiple "Press This" bookmarklets for different post types. Just change the post type in the snippet above and save a new bookmarklet.

Comment: I do mean custom taxonomy. I have multiple ones related to the 'post' post type but the only ones displayed in the Press This box are the standard category & tag.