# Quick Draft widget (dashboard.php) using custom post_type

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, dashboard, post-type

I'm trying to amend the WP dashboard widget 'Quick Draft' to accept a custom post_type avada_portfolio (Avada Fusion Theme) but the page just hangs each submission test.

There was a similar question here: [Adding Custom taxonomies to Press This panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191816/adding-custom-taxonomies-to-press-this-panel)

One member mentioned they had succeeded but unfortunately they removed their example due to the post being about 'Press This'.

I wonder if I am calling the post_type correctly. Any help would be gratefully received. This is as far as I have got:

```
/**
 * The Quick Draft widget display and creation of drafts.
 *
 * @since 3.8.0
 *
 * @global int $post_ID
 *
 * @param string $error_msg Optional. Error message. Default false.
 */
function wp_dashboard_quick_press( $error_msg = false ) {
    global $post_ID;

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    /* Check if a new auto-draft (= no new post_ID) is needed or if the old can be used */
    $last_post_id = (int) get_user_option( 'dashboard_quick_press_last_post_id' ); // Get the last post_ID
    if ( $last_post_id ) {
        $post = get_post( $last_post_id );
        if ( empty( $post ) || $post->post_status != 'auto-draft' ) { // auto-draft doesn't exists anymore
// MY REMOVE - $post = get_default_post_to_edit( 'post', true );
            $post = get_default_post_to_edit( $post_type = 'avada_portfolio', true );
            update_user_option( get_current_user_id(), 'dashboard_quick_press_last_post_id', (int) $post->ID ); // Save post_ID
        } else {
            $post->post_title = ''; // Remove the auto draft title
        }
    } else {
// MY REMOVE - $post    = get_default_post_to_edit( 'post', true );
        $post    = get_default_post_to_edit( $post_type = 'avada_portfolio', true );
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        // Don't create an option if this is a super admin who does not belong to this site.
        if ( in_array( get_current_blog_id(), array_keys( get_blogs_of_user( $user_id ) ) ) ) {
            update_user_option( $user_id, 'dashboard_quick_press_last_post_id', (int) $post->ID ); // Save post_ID
        }
    }

    $post_ID = (int) $post->ID;
    ?>

    <form name="post" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url( 'post.php' ) ); ?>" method="post" id="quick-press" class="initial-form hide-if-no-js">

        <?php if ( $error_msg ) : ?>
        <div class="error"><?php echo $error_msg; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="input-text-wrap" id="title-wrap">
            <label for="title">
                <?php
                /** This filter is documented in wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php */
                echo apply_filters( 'enter_title_here', __( 'Title' ), $post );
                ?>
            </label>
            <input type="text" name="post_title" id="title" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>

        <div class="textarea-wrap" id="description-wrap">
            <label for="content"><?php _e( 'Content' ); ?></label>
            <textarea name="content" id="content" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'What&#8217;s on your mind?' ); ?>" class="mceEditor" rows="3" cols="15" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
        </div>

        <p class="submit">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="quickpost-action" value="post-quickdraft-save" />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_ID" value="<?php echo $post_ID; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="avada_portfolio" />
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'add-post' ); ?>
            <?php submit_button( __( 'Save Draft' ), 'primary', 'save', false, array( 'id' => 'save-post' ) ); ?>
            <br class="clear" />
        </p>

    </form>
    <?php
    wp_dashboard_recent_drafts();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the Quick Draft widget is hardcoded in three places with no hooks supplied.

I've decided to go down the wp_insert_post route and write my own plugin :)